# How to consume JSON formatting with ruby's ActiveResource?

Tags: ruby, json, rest, activeresource

ActiveRecord introduced a change to its default JSON output format.  It went from

```
{ "user": { some_junk } }
```

to

```
{ some_junk }
```

ActiveResource has apparently followed their lead, expecting to consume JSON as

```
{ some_junk }
```

I am trying desperately to consume a  RESTful web service which emits

```
{ "user": { some_junk } }
```

Is there a way to tell my ActiveResource::Base class to do so?  Here's my code.

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
    self.site = "http://example.com/"
    self.format = :json
end
```

**Update**: I'm giving up on ActiveResource as broken for now, unless someone knows the answer; in the meantime, I was able to achieve the GET that I wanted via

```
require 'httparty' # sudo gem install httparty
result = HTTParty.get('http://foo.com/bar.json', headers => { "Foo" => "Bar"})
# result is a hash created from the JSON -- sweet!
```

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, ActiveResource is currently a bit inflexible when it comes to its data formats.

In principle, the idea is you could write yourself a custom format module (e.g. `JsonWithRootFormat`), based on the [`ActiveResource::Formats::JsonFormat`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f291fa528e5faad03def69ae7ac98224ab859db/activeresource/lib/active_resource/formats/json_format.rb) module, and then specify that as your format in your model:

```
self.format = :json_with_root
```

However, `ActiveResource::Base` isn't very format-agnostic -- it currently [does a check](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f291fa528e5faad03def69ae7ac98224ab859db/activeresource/lib/active_resource/base.rb#L905) to see whether you're using `XmlFormat`, and only passes the root node through if you are.

So you could get what you wanted by making your own format module, *and* monkey-patching `ActiveResource::Base`, but it's hardly ideal. I'm sure a patch to make `Base` a bit more format-agnostic would be welcomed, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good blog post by [@vaskas](http://twitter.com/vaskas) explaining how to write your own custom ActiveResource Formatter.

Using Hashes as ActiveResource Collections

http://vaskas.me/blog/2012/02/07/using-hashes-as-activeresource-collections/

Comment: The site is down but I tracked the post on his github (https://github.com/vaskas/vaskas.me/blob/master/blog/2012/02/07/using-hashes-as-activeresource-collections/index.html) - gist of it is you can assign your own format object to `self.format`. Create a new class, `include ActiveResource::Formats::JsonFormat` and define your own `decode` function.